# How do I run transactions in CakePHP3 for multiple model operation?

Tags: cakephp, transactions, cakephp-3.0

I want to use transactions on multiple insert/update query for multiple model/table.

In [cakephp3 documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions)  have an example of transaction using **connection manager** `execute()` method but I have to use transaction with `save()` method of cakephp3. I tried it using `save()` method but it didn't work. There was a SQL error, it execute all query and saving data except the query where the sql error have, rollback didn't work!

my code was like-

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

$connection->transactional(function ($connection) use($inputs, $status) {
  $serviceTbl = $this->Service;
  $service = $serviceTbl->newEntity();
  $service->name = $inputs['name'];
  $service = $serviceTbl->save($service);
if($service)
 {
   $this->loadModel('SrvApiClientInfo');
   $SrvApiClientInfo = $this->SrvApiClientInfo;
   $SrvApiClient = $SrvApiClientInfo->newEntity();
   $SrvApiClient->client_name = $inputs['basic_info']['client_name'];
   $SrvApiClient->organization_name = $inputs['basic_info']['vendor_name'];
   $SrvApiClient->address = $inputs['basic_info']['address'];
   $SrvApiClient->email = $inputs['basic_info']['email'];
   $SrvApiClient->mobile = $inputs['basic_info']['mobile'];
   $SrvApiClient->phone = $inputs['basic_info']['phone'];
   $SrvApiClient->fax = $inputs['basic_info']['fax'];
   $SrvApiClient->emergency_contact_name = $inputs['basic_info']['emergency_contact_name'];
   $SrvApiClient->emergency_contact_mobile = $inputs['basic_info']['emergency_contact_mobile'];
   $SrvApiClient->emergency_contact_designation = $inputs['basic_info']['emergency_contact_designation'];
   $SrvApiClient = $SrvApiClientInfo->save($SrvApiClient);
      if($SrvApiClient){
           $this->loadModel('ServiceApiRegistration');
           $tblServiceApiRegistration = $this->ServiceApiRegistration;
              foreach($inputs['method'] as $method)
              {
              $ServiceApiRegistration = $tblServiceApiRegistration->newEntity();
              $ServiceApiRegistration->service_id = $service['service_id'];
              $ServiceApiRegistration->service_api_id = $method;
              $ServiceApiRegistration->client_id = $SrvApiClient['client_id'];
              $ServiceApiRegistration->status_id = $status['Inactive'];
              $tblServiceApiRegistration->save($ServiceApiRegistration);
              }
         }
     }
    });
```

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Please be more specific as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. Also show your debugging attempts.

Comment: there was an sql error, it save all data but rollback didn't work!

Comment: What does your complete transactional code look like? And which DBMS and possible storage engine are you using?

Comment: i am using **mysql** and the storage engine **innodb**. i already mention the code, complete code are too big. i just inserting data in some table, like the service table operation.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's big, it is responsible for the rollback being triggered, and therefore essential for the question.

Comment: i update the code! can you ensure me that, is it the proper way to use transaction in cakephp3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs that you've linked a little more closely, especially point 3 and 4 of the "*The transactional method will do the following*" list

> The transactional method will do the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - If the closure raises an exception, a rollback will be issued. The original exception will be re-thrown.
> - If the closure returns false, a rollback will be issued.

Your code neither returns `false`, nor does it throw an exception when something goes wrong, hence no rollback will be issued.

If there really was an SQL "error", ie an exception triggered in the core, then it should have been catched by the transaction wrapper, and a rollback should have been issued. So I'd suspect that either, there was no exception, or that rollbacks aren't supported or the driver *thinks* they aren't.